# Grab a character from a word based on specified parameters

Tags: vba, ms-word

So say I have a couple of words of various length, and I want to have a MsgBox display the third character from the end for each of them. How would I do that with WordVBA?

For example:

```
Stack would return "a"
123.45 would return "."
Agent001 would return "0"

etc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Left, Right, and Mid (with or without Reverse). The traditional ways.

```
Left(Right(A,3),1)

Mid(A, Len(A) - 3, 1)
```